# Display numbers instead of points using pyplot

Tags: arrays, matplotlib, numbers, point

I have a nx2 dimension array representing n points with their two coordinates x, y. Using pyplot, I would like to display the number n of my points instead of just the points with no way to know which is what.

I have found a way to legend my points but really what I would like is only the number.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Could be a duplicate, however I was interpreting the title and last sentence in the question such that user has already found a solution such as the one from the linked question, but does not like it. Improving the quesiton may help understanding if this is the case or not.

Comment: It is the case, I would like numbers showing up **instead** of points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use `plt.text` to place the number as text in the plot. To have the number appear at the exact position of the coordinates, you may center align the text using `ha="center", va="center"`.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(2)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xy = np.random.rand(10,2)

plt.figure()
for i, ((x,y),) in enumerate(zip(xy)):
    plt.text(x,y,i, ha="center", va="center")

plt.show()
```

[image]

In order to have the plot autoscale to the range where the values are, you may add an invisible scatter plot

```
x,y =zip(*xy)
plt.scatter(x,y, alpha=0)
```

or, if numbers are really small, better an invisible plot

```
x,y =zip(*xy)
plt.plot(x,y, alpha=0.0)
```

Comment: Thank you ! Your code works for me and this what I want except that I use a normal distribution so I have `xy = np.random.normal(0, 1, (10, 2))` instead and see nothing displayed :/

Comment: The values are out of the plotting range. See updated answer.

Comment: The scaling seems to work except for very small values (10^-12). Do you know how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Which problem ?

Comment: I see. In that case better make an invisible plot instead of a scatter. I updated the answer.

Comment: When I plot points with very small values, I have to zoom many times on a small rectangle where all the points are concentrated before I can actually see the points distinctly. I would like the axes to be scaled to the figure so that I don't have to zoom.